# Temperature control with interacting PID loops

Tags: mechanical-engineering

I want to control the temperature of a steel mold about 300 mm square by 1000 mm high. The mold has ten electic cartridge heaters installed in it. There are ten corresponding thermo-couples, one near each heater. Each heater/thermocouple pair is a zone. The simple solution is to use ten PID loops, one for each zone.

The problem is that the zones interact, and heat from one zone's heater heats the other zones too. The closer the zones are to each other the more they affect each other. The output of each PID loop will be a disturbance to each other PID zone. The specification is to control each zone to $\pm 1 {^\circ} C$.

A control system using proportional controllers (P term only) in each zone was tried. The temperature of each zone oscillated, far exceeding the $\pm 1 {^\circ} C$ requirement. The system would never settle. This isn't suprising with strict proportional control. I expect that a PID control would work better, but I don't know what the interactions will do.

Will multiple interacting PID control zones stabilize? Is there a better approach to controlling the system?

Edit: All zone set-points are the same temperature. They all need follow a linearly increasing temperature profile from $20^\circ C$ to $180^\circ C$ over twenty hours. The internal cavity of the mold has a very irregular shape.

Comment: Important information missing: are all ten temperature setpoints equal? Hit the edit link below your question ... Tip: SE supports HTML entities: `&deg;`for degrees symbol, `&pm;`for +/- symbol, etc. It also supports `<sup>...</sup>`and `<sub>...</sub>`for superscript and subscript.

Comment: Oh interesting question! Can you update with some more specifications, volume of the object, and the set points of each thermocouple?

Comment: It seems to me you could add negative feedback to controllers from the adjacent controller signals based on how close they are. But how to tune them exactly is beyond me.

Answer (score 2):

What you need is call a multi input multi output (MIMO) state space controller. There's lot of tutorials on this online if you search. Short summary is that you'll build several matrices that describe the influence of each heater on every sensor. E.g. Response at sensor 3 due to a step change in power at heater 7. From this matrix your controller will be able to set the power to all heaters in order to reduce error at all sensors simultaneously

Comment: Thanks. I checked out some of the tutorials. From a practical standpoint, with the real mold, how do I figure out the terms? It seems that I would have to get the mold to an even, steady-state temperature by manually manipulating gains on each zone. And then I would change one zone's gain, measure how it affects each zone, and solve the matrix. I would do this for each zone. Once I have the steady-state gain matrix complete, would that be the P terms (or relative P terms) for the dynamic control system? I would then experiment to find appropriate I and D terms?

Comment: I don't see how MIMO performs dynamic control.

Comment: There is also such a thing as a MIMO transfer function, if you don't want to do state space control.  see for example https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/978-1-4471-2425-2_6  But either way you'll have to do MIMO something.  You figure out the terms by doing a series of experiment. will have to get the system to steady state, but it doesn't have to be even or uniform at all sensors.  then you would change the power of one of the heaters (e.g. step change, or sinusoidal modulation) and determine the resulting change in temperature at all of the sensors.

Comment: Thank you for the link. I appreciate your help.